# How to sort month years from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a list from mysql db which includes months combined with years that need to be sorted accordingly. At the moment the returned list (ordered DESC) looks like this:

```
122015 - (Dec 2015)
112015 - (Nov 2015)
102015 - (Oct 2015)
92015 - (Sep 2015)
82015 - (Aug 2015)
12016 - (Jan 2016)
```

I would like the above list to follow logical sorting with Jan 2016 being top of the list e.g.

```
12016 - (Jan 2016)
122015 - (Dec 2015)
112015 - (Nov 2015)
102015 - (Oct 2015)
92015 - (Sep 2015)
82015 - (Aug 2015)
```

How do I go about achieving this in php?

*Update
the sql query I used is:

```
SELECT mnthyears FROM dates ORDER BY mnthyears DESC
```

Comment: Don't use PHP to sort, make the database do it.

Comment: Is this a text field? If it is, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Please write your sql query and table structure in your question and better way to use sql query for change order not use php.

Comment: your table structure... ?

Comment: added sql code @Jalpa

Comment: @RupertForbes Also tell me field data type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mysql LPAD (padding function) combined with SUBSTR method in ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT mnthyears
FROM dates
ORDER BY SUBSTR(LPAD( mnthyears, 19, '0'),3,4) DESC, SUBSTR(LPAD(mnthyears,19,'0'),1,2) DESC
```

If however you have only those 5 or 6 digits strings (without "`- (Dec 2015)`"), just change **19** to **6**

Comment: That would leave dates from multiple years jumbled up.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins thanks for correction, I have just edited it.

Comment: @n-dru This is perfect! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `str_to_date`

```
str_to_date(replace(replace('(Jan 2016)',')',''),'(',''),'%b  %Y')
```

Query

```
SELECT mnthyears FROM dates 
ORDER BY str_to_date(replace(replace('(Jan 2016)',')',''),'(',''),'%b  %Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the **length** of your date string changes, you should be able to pull this off inside your SQL code - no need to do it in PHP afterwards

```
select case when len(mnthyears ) = 18 then '0'+mnthyears else date_column end 
   as mnthyears FROM dates ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```